# Running Powershell command from .bat script doesn't work, however it works when I type it directly in Command Line

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, devops

```
Powershell -Command "cat .\tmp.txt | %{$_ -replace '\D', ''}"
```

Why running above Powershell command from .bat script doesn't work?
It works only when I type it directly in Command Line...

Running from .bat script produces the following message:

```
    Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
    At line:1 char:39
+ cat .\tmp.txt | {$_ -replace '\D', ''} <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`powershell /?` gives this help text (trimmed below to show only the relevant text).

```
-Command
...
To write a string that runs a Windows PowerShell command, use the format:
    "& {<command>}"
where the quotation marks indicate a string and the invoke operator (&)
causes the command to be executed.
```

So your batch file powrshell line needs to read:

```
powershell -Command "&{ cat .\tmp.txt | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\D', ''} }"
```

(note the extra curly braces wrapped around your command and `%` being replaced with `ForEach-Object`)

Comment: It was the % which DOS is trying to interpret. See my amendment.

Comment: @Quak If length is an issue you coud simply double the percent sign to have it working in a batch (this is also the case with the for variables)